# Is it possible to push an object when I touch it by moving another object in Object Mode?

Tags: transforms, object-mode

I have created 2 cubes and I want to know how to consider each cube, in ***Object Mode***, as a real solid (without gravity) and so:

- when I move one cube to another cube this second cube moves too when the first cube touch one of its faces.
- and this second cube stop to move as soon as the first object no longer touches the second object.

Comment: Thank you very much @Bruno .

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using RigidBodies:

1. add a ground (large cube), make it a passive ridig body
2. add rigidbody to the two other cubes sitting on the ground, check the "Rigidbody/Animated" box for the 1st cube
3. hit space to play the animation then move the first cube toward the second. Collisions should happen...

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Bruno ! ---  But I also want a to be able to work in the _**Object Mode**_ without to play animation ! ---- Is it possible  ? ---  Perhaps with an addon or a code ?